# Demonstrate that $m_n = max(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a sufficient statistic .

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let $X1, . . . , Xn$ be independent and identically distributed with density
$P_θ(x) = $ \begin{cases}
 2x/θ^2  & \text{for }0\le x<θ\\    
  0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
Demonstrate that $m_n = max(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a sufficient statistic .

This is what i did so far, but i'm a bit stuck.
I found the likelihood to be:

$L(θ) = $ \begin{cases}
 (2/θ^2)^n \prod x_i & \text{if}max (x_1,...,x_n) ≤ θ\\    
  0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}

I know that $L(θ)  = g(x)h(T(x),θ)$. But im not sure which is which. Do i use the RHS ($max(x1...)$) or LHS (($2/θ^2)^n$....)?

Would really appreciate the help.

Edit: is $g(x) = 1$ here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to express all constraints inside your function, resulting in a density of the form

$$f_{\bf X} (x) = h(x)g(\theta, T({x})),$$

where $T$ is the sufficient statistic, in our case

$$T(x) = \max (x_1,\dots,x_n).$$

To do this, rewrite the expression for the density as follows:

\begin{align*} f_{\bf X} (x) &= \left(\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{2x_j{\bf 1}_{\{x_j>0\}}}{\theta^2}\right){\bf 1}_{\{\max(x_1,\dots,x_n)\le \theta\}}\\
&= \underset{=h(x)}{\underbrace{\left(\prod_{n=1}^n  2x_j{\bf 1}_{\{x_j>0\}}\right)}}\times \underset{=g(\theta,T(x))}{\underbrace{\theta^{-2n} \times {\bf 1}_{\{\max(x_1,\dots,x_n)\le \theta\}}}}
\end{align*}